# Relevant mathematics to the recent coronavirus outbreak

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, applied-mathematics, epidemics-modeling

I would like to ask about (old* and new) reliable mathematical literature relevant to various mathematical aspects of the recent coronavirus outbreak: In particular, standard statistical/mathematical models that are used to predict the spread, mathematical studies of effectiveness of various strategies, etc.

*(Added) By old I also mean well-established models.

Comment: Out of respect though , if this question was asked by someone anonymous it will be closed in seconds .

Comment: Mathematically, I doubt that there's anything particularly new about this coronavirus.  Mathematical models of epidemics are well-established.   
Of course we'd like to know the parameters (and to what extent something can be done about them). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_modelling_of_infectious_disease)

Comment: Random walk on graphs?

Comment: There are many. Here is a recent article of my friend: https://bmcinfectdis.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2334-3-19

Comment: @MarkSapir I have to disagree - I think this question is simply far too broad for MO. (I won't vote to close because I have absolutely no background in the relevant topic, however.)

Comment: @MarkSapir, when a link to Wikipedia is an appropriate response to a question, it's not research level.

Comment: @MattF: Wikipedia text does not deal with the last 15 years of investigation which you can see for yourself if you look at the article.

Comment: Regarding new research motivated by the outbreak, I found 3 papers on the arxive https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=coronavirus&terms-0-field=abstract&classification-mathematics=y&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=include&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first

Comment: Glenn Webb is a very good mathematician. I am sure he knows everything there is to know about the subject. You may want to ask him your questiom directly.

Comment: I liked this question, I wish it wasn't closed. Not everything that can be known about the mathematics of pandemics has been discovered and the novel coronavirus is as good an opportunity as any to motivate new results.

Comment: PLOS started the ["Mathematical Modelling of Infectious Disease Dynamics Collection"](https://blogs.plos.org/everyone/2020/02/20/mathematical-disease-dynamics/), about the spreading some literature can be found [here](https://cmmid-lshtm.shinyapps.io/traveller_screening), values for [R0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_reproduction_number#References)[4,5],[CFR](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/coronavirus-death-rate/) could be interesting too, google has lots of stuff but more qualitatively could be useful this course by [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/csels/dsepd/ss1978/index.html)

Comment: @Bambi ,  In retrospect, the question was closed and also the users' votes were not favorable.  So I don't think this is a case where anonymous user would have great disadvantage. Probably I could have done a better job in writing the question (so I did not vote to reopen myself) and I hope (as a non expert) that at some time better questions will be asked both regarding well-established models of epidemics, and about specific mathematical issues related to the current outbreak.

Comment: @Gil Kalai First of all I have to tell you this , I've enormous respect for you and I'm follower of your work on quantum computing . I didn't expect that this comment will get such attention. I just mentioned this because I've seen various questions of above form getting closed immediately on MO . Again apologies if I'm being rude .( After this comment three of my own MO questions got downvotes )( I didn't even vote to close it )

Comment: @Bambi, no problems...

Comment: @GilKalai if you expand to include q-bio you go from 3 hits to 24, many of which are at least math-adjacent if not outright actual math.

Comment: Not epidemics and more cs than math but could be interesting anyway, some [data](https://deepmind.com/research/open-source/computational-predictions-of-protein-structures-associated-with-COVID-19) on the protein structure is being released now and this is done by [alphafold](https://venturebeat.com/2018/12/03/deepminds-alphafold-wins-casp13-protein-folding-competition/) [+](https://moalquraishi.wordpress.com/2018/12/09/alphafold-casp13-what-just-happened/) which changed protein prediction in 2018 just as [imagenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageNet) changed visual recognition back in 2012

Comment: I was thinking to ask such question, but I afraid of that it is not suitable for here. Anyway, there are many good epidemics modeling by the NetLogo software for HIV, Ebola, flue and many others.
I think by redefining and tuning the existing model, we can find some good new models for COVID-19.

Comment: Possibly unrelated (I'm not a professional mathematician and I don't know the following resources) to your specific question about the coronavirus outbreak in this site is that the official channel **Centre International de Rencontres Mathématiques** is editing from its YouTube channel recent videos that maybe are related (in my view) to models of epidemics, for example by Malwina Luczak and other  by Simon Frost. I have not looked for more references as video lectures in other math channels that I know. Isn't required a response of this message, and I hope don't disturb.

Comment: An interesting MSRI (online) lecture by Nicholas Jewell https://youtu.be/MZ957qhzcjI

Comment: I tried to answer you in 

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355489/suggestings-for-reducing-the-transmission-rate

Comment: On Terry Tao's blog: Polymath proposal: clearinghouse for crowdsourcing COVID-19 data and data cleaning requests. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/03/25/polymath-proposal-clearinghouse-for-crowdsourcing-covid-19-data-and-data-cleaning-requests/

Comment: IEEE is giving free access to all COVID-19-related papers. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=%22Free%20Promotions%22:COVID-19

Comment: [The Centre for the Mathematical Modelling of Infectious Diseases](https://cmmid.github.io/) recently made a [study](https://cmmid.github.io/topics/covid19/severity/global_cfr_estimates.html) on the under-reporting of cases by country (here is a [article](https://www.usnews.com/news/world-report/articles/2020-04-06/the-flaws-in-coronavirus-case-reporting-data) but some of what is written may differ on more recent data), this is not math focused but hopefully still useful

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is the whole discipline of math models of epidemics.

See, for example, Fitzgibbon, William E.(1-HST); Morgan, Jeffery J.(1-HST); Webb, Glenn F.(1-VDB); Wu, Yixiang(1-VDB)
Spatial models of vector-host epidemics with directed movement of vectors over long distances. (English summary)
Math. Biosci. 312 (2019), 77–87

and the references there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mark!

Answer (score 13):

Maybe relevant:

> Yu Chen, Jin Cheng, Yu Jiang, Keji Liu, *A Time Delay Dynamical Model for Outbreak of 2019-nCoV and the Parameter Identification*, https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.00418

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Martin!

Answer (score 9):

The following paper is a little strange, since it dates back to 2015, but has some valuable data:

- [A SARS-like cluster of circulating bat coronaviruses shows potential for human emergence](https://doi.org/10.1038/nm.3985), Nature Medicine, 2015.

Comment: Here is another case from february 2019 [**"Bat Coronaviruses in China"**](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4915/11/3/210/htm) from the abstract "Thus, it is highly likely that future SARS- or MERS-like coronavirus outbreaks will originate from bats, and there is an increased probability that this will occur in China."

Comment: @Daniel D. And it is more strange why we do not have any kind of vaccination by these predictions!?

Comment: There exists the ["Coalition for Epidemic Preparedness Innovations (CEPI)"](https://cepi.net/) which was created after the Ebola outbreak and is leading the efforts in the creation of a vaccine but is not the only one so there are a lot of news and I would say is not clear were this race is going yet, on the other hand for MERS there was no vaccine either so it seems to me what was done first was to test if the treatments for MERS were also effective against COVID-19 in particular [Remdesivir and chloroquine](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41422-020-0282-0)

Comment: For completeness sake let me add a another paper that I have read on the [news](https://theprint.in/health/ticking-time-bomb-study-predicted-re-emergence-of-sars-like-virus-13-years-ago/386236/) more or less had foreseen the situation:[Severe Acute Respiratory Syndrome Coronavirus as an Agent of Emerging and Reemerging Infection](https://cmr.asm.org/content/20/4/660)

Answer (score 8):

The book by Gábor Csárdi, Tamás Nepusz,  Edoardo Airoldi, 
*[Statistical Network Analysis with igraph](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~airoldi/pub/books/BookDraft-CsardiNepuszAiroldi2016.pdf)*

Based around popular software library [igraph](https://igraph.org/), [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igraph)
contains whole chapter with **source codes (in R)** on *Epidemics on networks* in particular  *6.5 Vaccination strategies*

Let me quote the content of the chapter:

```
6 Epidemics on networks
6.2  Branching processes
6.3  Compartmental models on homogeneous populations
6.3.1  The susceptible-infected-recovered (SIR) model
6.3.2  The susceptible-infected-susceptible (SIS) model
6.3.3  The susceptible-infected-recovered-susceptible (SIRS)model
6.4  Compartmental models on networks
6.4.1  A general framework for compartmental models onnetworks
6.4.2  Epidemics on regular and geometric networks . . . . . . . . 180
6.4.3  Epidemics on scale-free networks . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 187
6.5  Vaccination strategies . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alexander!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a recent paper written by mathematicians: [Risk Assessment of Novel Coronavirus COVID-19 Outbreaks Outside China](https://www.mdpi.com/2077-0383/9/2/571).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matt!

Comment: @GilKalai: My name is not Matt (and I wrote this answer), but thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, GH from MO!

Answer (score 5):

Recently found this :

https://staff.math.su.se/tom.britton/

Maybe relevant.

Comment: Here is a related videotaped lecture by Britton, https://youtu.be/gSqIwXl6IjQ

Comment: @GilKalai Wow , thanks , I didn't know about video

Answer (score 4):

The following paper is extremely important because it has informed the decisions of the UK government that realised (announced) on Monday 16/03/2020 that it can not afford "Herd immunity". The paper only shows the outcomes of the model and speaks about its parameters. It would of course be extremely interesting to know what exactly is the mathematics behind it. Mathematicians should try to read it.

https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/medicine/sph/ide/gida-fellowships/Imperial-College-COVID19-NPI-modelling-16-03-2020.pdf?fbclid=IwAR2Ca5Ki23DWn-EGWeB3yaNE4f9GmnUcEWU_S60lsDC230AKUg4v_w82qeE

Comment: Thanks for the answer, aglearner!

Comment: Here is a related mathematical discussion on Gowers' blog: https://gowers.wordpress.com/2020/03/28/how-long-should-a-lockdown-relaxation-cycle-last/

Answer (score 1):

[Volume 12 of *What's Happening in the Mathematical Sciences*](https://bookstore.ams.org/happening-12/) by Dana Mackenzie has three chapters devoted to mathematical modeling related to the coronavirus pandemic.

> **Fifty Ways to Beat a Virus (Part 1)**
> In 2020, the world for the first time in a century confronted
> a global pandemic that would claim millions of lives. While
> students were sent home and campuses closed, many mathematicians found an opportunity to join the fight against
> COVID-19. Even simple differential equation models can teach
> us important lessons about the exponential growth of a new
> epidemic and the importance of threshold behavior. Using
> more elaborate (and realistic) models, two mathematical
> modeling groups, in Texas and Illinois, had a profound and
> positive effect on the management of the epidemic by local and
> state authorities during the first waves.
>
> **Fifty Ways to Beat a Virus (Part 2)**
> Continuing the previous chapter, Part 2 discusses the problems
> confronted by mathematicians and epidemiologists in the later
> part of 2020 and in early 2021. How could universities re-open
> safely? How does the uncontrolled spread of an epidemic in
> prisons affect the surrounding community, and what can be
> done about it? And the biggest question: could vaccination
> bring the epidemic under control? Even though the coronavirus
> kept throwing surprises at us, mathematicians did a surprisingly good job of developing strategies, giving realistic answers
> and highlighting the main reasons for uncertainty.
>
> **Fifty Ways to Beat a Virus (Part 3)**
> Another important front in the battle against COVID-19 was
> to understand how the infection progresses within the human
> body. Why do some people have life-threatening symptoms,
> while others have none at all? An online group called the
> “Immune Gals” highlighted the delayed release of interferon
> as a characteristic marker of severe cases. Another mathematician used the tools of graph theory to identify parts of the
> viral RNA that are especially vulnerable to attack by drugs or
> gene therapy. And a third group adapted a machine-learning
> language model to detect escape variants of coronavirus. In
> effect, they taught the computer to “speak virus.”